# Anylogic- Placing agents on other agent's location

Tags: anylogic, agent

I am having two agents, agentA(evStations) (initial location and numbers are loaded from a database), and an AgentB(eVs) (initially empty and the number of agents is specified by the user).

At the model start up, I want to place AgentsB at the locations of AgentA (exact latitude and longitude). How can I do that? **Knowing that the number of AgentB is much larger than AgnetA.**

What i have tried(based on an existing anylogic example), on the main> Agent actions> On startup

```
for(EV ev: eVs){
    ev.set_lat(
        selectFrom(evstations)
            .where(evstations.id.eq(ev.getIndex()))
            .firstResult(evstations.latitude)
    );
    ev.set_lon(
        selectFrom(evstations)
            .where(evstations.id.eq(ev.getIndex()))
            .firstResult(evstations.logtitude)
    );
    ev.setLocation(ev.lat, ev.lon);
}
        [enter image description here][1]
```

i am not sure how to do it correctly, I think this only works if both agents are having the same size.
Please advise?

thanks

Comment: if agentAs is 100 and agentsB is 150, you can put the first 100 in the same locations, but where do you want to put the other 50?

Comment: it is the opposite, agentA is around 10 locations, while agenB is 50. I want the 50 agents of B to be randomly distributed among the 10 locations of agent B.

Comment: then it's not the opposite :P

Comment: ohh yes, you are right.

Comment: agentA is around 10 locations, while agenB is 50. I want the 50 agents of B to be distributed among the 10 locations of agent B. Not necessarily randomly distributed, like one agnetB to have a 10 and the other only 3. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

first define all the evStations as agents, you can read them from the database.

Then

```
for(EV ev: eVs){
    EvStation evs=evStations.random();
    ev.setLocation(evs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't think it works. As i wrote another function to check if the ev is at the evStation,                                                                                                                          (for( EV ev : eVs ){
    if (commuter.evDestination1.distanceByRoute( ev ) == 0)
    commuter.ev=ev;
        return false;) but it doesn't return the expected value.

Comment: i think your problem there is different... i don't know what the commuter is so i can't help you